# Select few commits from a Pull Request for merging in Github

Tags: github

Is it possible to select/approve just a few out of all the commits inside a Pull Request on Github for merge ?

Thanks !

Edit 1 : I am looking for an option to select commits from the Github UI itself and not from the command line.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/8936320

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)

Comment: Hi Ishan, i was looking for an answer from the UI. Thanks though !

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it seems that this is not possible using the GitHub UI. There is an year old [request for this](https://github.community/t/feature-request-cherry-pick-commits-from-ui/1842) in the GitHub forum, but no update seems to be available since then.